# swift Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'Int!'

Tags: swift, xcode6, operators, unary-operator

In the section Basic Operators, the Swift Programming Language guide states that ++ is a valid operator:

> “More complex examples include the logical AND operator && (as in if
>   enteredDoorCode && passedRetinaScan) and the increment operator ++i,
>   which is a shortcut to increase the value of i by 1.” Excerpt From:
>   Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks.
>   https://itun.es/gb/jEUH0.l

However, when attempting this in a playground:

```
class Levels {
    var data = [
        [
            "nodesNum" : 20,
            "lastLevel" : false
        ],
        [
            "nodesNum" : 16,
            "lastLevel" : false
        ],
        [
            "nodesNum" : 13,
            "lastLevel" : false
        ],
        [
            "nodesNum" : 10,
            "lastLevel" : false
        ],
        [
            "nodesNum" : 8,
            "lastLevel" : true
        ]
    ]
}

var levels: Levels!
var availableNodesNum: Int!
var currentLevelData: NSDictionary!
var levelNum:Int = 2

levels = Levels()

currentLevelData = levels.data[levelNum]
availableNodesNum = Int(currentLevelData["nodesNum"]! as! NSNumber)

println(currentLevelData)
println(availableNodesNum)

availableNodesNum++
```

A build error shows:

> swift Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type
>   'Int!'

Why? Thnx for all your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you should unwrap it first

```
availableNodesNum!++
```

because in the standard library `++` is only defined for non-optionals as a prefix and postfix operator.

```
prefix public func ++(inout x: UInt8) -> UInt8

prefix public func ++(inout rhs: Float80) -> Float80

postfix public func ++(inout lhs: Double) -> Double

postfix public func ++(inout lhs: Float) -> Float

prefix public func ++(inout rhs: Float) -> Float

postfix public func ++(inout x: Int) -> Int

prefix public func ++(inout x: Int) -> Int

postfix public func ++(inout x: UInt) -> UInt

prefix public func ++(inout x: UInt) -> UInt

/// Replace `i` with its `successor()` and return the original
/// value of `i`.
postfix public func ++<T : _Incrementable>(inout i: T) -> T

postfix public func ++(inout x: Int64) -> Int64

prefix public func ++(inout x: Int64) -> Int64

postfix public func ++(inout x: UInt64) -> UInt64

prefix public func ++(inout x: UInt64) -> UInt64

/// Replace `i` with its `successor()` and return the updated value of
/// `i`.
prefix public func ++<T : _Incrementable>(inout i: T) -> T

postfix public func ++(inout x: Int32) -> Int32

prefix public func ++(inout x: Int32) -> Int32

postfix public func ++(inout x: UInt32) -> UInt32

postfix public func ++(inout lhs: Float80) -> Float80

prefix public func ++(inout x: UInt32) -> UInt32

postfix public func ++(inout x: Int16) -> Int16

prefix public func ++(inout x: Int16) -> Int16

postfix public func ++(inout x: UInt16) -> UInt16

prefix public func ++(inout x: UInt16) -> UInt16

postfix public func ++(inout x: Int8) -> Int8

prefix public func ++(inout x: Int8) -> Int8

postfix public func ++(inout x: UInt8) -> UInt8

prefix public func ++(inout rhs: Double) -> Double
```

& bear in mind that according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) :

> An implicitly unwrapped optional is a normal optional behind the
>   scenes

You'll get the same error if you use unary operator with an optional

```
var a : Int? = 12
a++ //Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'Int?'
```

Comment: What's the point of an implicitly unwrapped optional if you have to unwrap it again? This seems like a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type '@lvalue Int'

So You just use this

if you use to increment then

> i = +1 instead of i++

if you use in loop then try this

```
for i in 0..<xList.count{
print(i) // for int
print(xList[i]) // for value
}
```

instead of

```
for var i = 0; i<xList.count; i++{
print(i)
print(xList[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `!` at the end of `var availableNodesNum: Int!`